# msbuild - unauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344

Tags: iis, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, unauthorized

I am using MSBuld task to change the virtual directory of an IIS Site hosted on windows 2012 server. I am using following code:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website TaskAction="Stop"
                                               Name="TestSite"
                                               MachineName="$(MachineName)"/>
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website TaskAction="ModifyPath"
                                               Name="TestSite"
                                               Path="$(PublishDir)"
                                               MachineName="$(MachineName)"/>
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website TaskAction="Start"
                                                                     Name="TestSite"
                                               MachineName="$(MachineName)"/>
```

I am performing two task:

1. Copy files from my machine to remote machine, which is working fine. Meaning I have read and write access on remote machine.
2. In the step two, I am trying to change the virtual directory using ms build task, which is failing.

I am getting following error when I try to change the virtual directory of a IIS site either on same machine or on different machine.

**UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine XXXX failed due to the following error: 80070005**

I am using same code on windows 2008 server to change virtual directory path of another website hosted on a different machine & it is working fine.

I looked around for similar issue & most of the people talking about suing user-name and password of a person having admin right other machine or make some changes in registry. I do not want to use these two approaches.

Is there any other work around?

Comment: The error code 80070005 is a access denied. I would suggest making sure your user has the privileges to manage the iis instance on that machine.

Comment: @MaxYoung: Please give me more details. Where to check.. what to do? I am performing two steps. In the step no 1, From my computer to this remote machine, I am copying files which is working fine and in the second step I am using msbuild to change the virtual directory, which is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, I was running the task using Team City (continuous integration server) which in turn used ms-build task to change the virtual directory. Team city was running under a service account. I had to **add that service account under Administrators group on the remote machine**.